# CPU time is always zero :(

Tags: c++, c, time, cpu

I am trying to measure CPU time using following code.

```
timespec time1, time2, temp_time;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
 int i;
 int cpu_sum = 0;


 for (i = 0; i < nelements; i++) {

  cpu_sum += array[i];

 }    
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);
temp_time.tv_sec = time2.tv_sec - time1.tv_sec;
printf( sum: %d using CPU in %lf ms \n",cpu_sum, temp_time.tv_sec);
```

But I always get time as 0.000ms
Any idea what is wrong here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You're not checking the `clock_gettime(3)` calls for error returns; check the return value and use `perror(3)` to output an error message if an error was returned.

Comment: `clock_gettime` should never return an error when given valid arguments.

Comment: @R..: Not all clocks are available on all platforms; user958263 didn't show the `sysconf(3)` code to verify that the clocks he is using are available on his platform, so I'm curious if it has failed because they aren't supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You're invoking undefined behavior by passing the wrong argument types to `printf` (`time_t`, which is probably `long`, instead of `double`).
2. `tv_sec` just contains the whole seconds part of the time. You need to also use `tv_nsec` to get the nanoseconds part.

Try something like:

```
temp_time.tv_sec = time2.tv_sec - time1.tv_sec;
temp_time.tv_nsec = time2.tv_nsec - time2.tv_nsec;
if (temp_time.tv_nsec < 0) {
    temp_time.tv_nsec += 1000000000;
    temp_time.tv_sec--;
}
printf("%lld.%.9ld\n", (long long)temp_time.tv_sec, (long)temp_time.tv_nsec);
```

Comment: `time_t` could be an integer or floating type, POSIX allows either.

Comment: It could be, but in practice it never is. Even if it were, when used in timespec, it would still only store whole numbers.

Comment: @dreamlax: FYI, POSIX 2008 requires it to be an integer type.

Comment: @R..: That's good to know. I have never encountered a system that uses a floating `time_t` but every time I use the `time_t` type I always consider the possibility. Going forward this is going to be much less of an issue!

Answer (score 1):

The above won't compile as-is but there is one obvious problem: you're only looking at the `tv_sec` fields and not the `tv_nsec` fields.  The two `tv_sec` values, which measure whole seconds, will likely be identical because much less than one entire second of CPU time will elapse.

To subtract two timespec structure values (untested):

```
void ts_delta(struct timespec *result, struct timespec *a, struct timespec *b) {
    int borrow = 0;
    long n = a->tv_nsec - b->tv_nsec;

    if (n < 0) { /* nsec underflow; borrow 1 from seconds */
        n += 1000000000L;
        borrow = 1;
    }
    result->tv_nsec = n;
    result->tv_sec = a->tv_sec - b->tv_sec - borrow;
}
```

Comment: @R..: I did!  I usually rely on compiling with `-W -Wall` to catch type errors in C.

Comment: And how do i print the time in this case?

Comment: @R..'s answer has a good method for printing the result.  Note, I have no idea whether your system can even capture the time taken for a small sum (e.g., if `nelements` is only a few tens of thousands).

Comment: If it's Linux, `clock_gettime` actually has nanosecond precision on modern systems. For cpu time (which is in some ways easier to measure than real time), it's almost surely that precise.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying on Linux.

In my system it prints like the following. You can check and let me know if it works.

```
ayub@gentux ~ $ cat cputime.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
  struct timespec time1, time2, temp_time;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
  int i;
  int cpu_sum = 0;
  static int array[1000]; /* 'static' to make the array initialized to zero by default (for demo) */
  int nelements = 1000;
  long diff = 0;

  array[0] = 10;
  for (i = 0; i < nelements; i++) {
    cpu_sum += array[i];
  }    
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);
  temp_time.tv_sec = time2.tv_sec - time1.tv_sec;
  temp_time.tv_nsec = time2.tv_nsec - time1.tv_nsec;
  diff = temp_time.tv_sec * 1000000000 + temp_time.tv_nsec; /* total ns */
  printf("Sum: %d using CPU in %lf ms \n", cpu_sum, (double) diff/1000000); /* now we print as milisecond */

  return 0;
}

ayub@gentux ~ $ gcc -o cputime cputime.c -lrt
ayub@gentux ~ $ time ./cputime
Sum: 10 using CPU in 0.003197 ms 

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
ayub@gentux ~ $ ./cputime 
Sum: 10 using CPU in 0.002599 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The gnu libc manual has some good info, and even includes an example subtraction function

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html